# About this in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am confused about the way this behaves in some circumstances for example I have this code

```
var makeRequest=function(url,callback){

  var data=10; 

  callback(data);
};

var obj = {
  someValue: 20,
  loadData: function(data){
    var sum = this.someValue + data;
    alert(sum);
  },
  prepareRequest:function(){
    var url="http://someurl.com";

    makeRequest(url,obj.loadData);

  }
};
```

It makes a request let s say and it gets some data. The thing is when I call the function `makeRequest` with `obj.loadData` as parameter it gives an error.
Can someone explain why it happens this? Why it doesn t behave the expected way when i call `obj.prepareRequest()` even tho the `loadData` method is attacked to `obj` object? 
I would appreciate any help. "This" keyword is really confusing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Within your function "loadData", "this" does not refer to your object, but the function itself. Read up on variable scope in JavaScript

Comment: Functions, without explicit binding, are in no way permanently associated with objects. When you pass `obj.loadData` as the callback, the relationship to `obj` is lost. You can use `obj.loadData.bind(obj)` to create a function that *is* bound to the object.

Comment: Maybe read [_this_](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#chapter-2-this-all-makes-sense-now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point when you passed your `loadData` function as a parameter into `makeRequest` just think of switching ownership ... `makeRequest` **now owns** `loadData` 
so if there's any `this` keyword being used in `loadData` then it is referring to `makeRequest` not `obj` .

The way to maintain ownership or context is to use `.bind()`

`loadData` has no clue what `this.someValue` is because the **context was changed**

In your `prepareRequest` function add `bind` and good practice is to use `this` for oop purposes

**Example**

```
makeRequest(url,this.loadData.bind(this));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: So what you mean is that even though  loadData  is a method attached to the obj object  because is also a parameter of makeRequest and since makeRequest is a function which is an object in javascript now loadData is attached to makeRequest object . Is what i understand so far. I hope i got it right